# How to center an element vertically in a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm practising making a form and I would like to position the form elements on the left in the centre of their row sort of how it would automatically be done with a table. Here is some [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W792X/11/) for what i've been attempting so far.

How do I vertically centre the label element for a form?

Comment: Are you trying to center your labels vertically?

Comment: @Steve Adams yes. For example. The "feedback" could be vertically centred beside the select box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `label` same height as `input filed` have & give `line-height` to your `label`. Like this:

```
.element label {
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 156px;
}
```

Comment: is not a hacky. We use this technique when we want a text vertical middle.

Comment: Not hacky, that's works flawlessly in every browser. Centering text vertically using line-height is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks :-). I'm quite novice so I'm quite cautious to learn what is right. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and setup the position after the elements are loaded.  Minor adjustments to HTML (assign IDs):

```
            <div class="element">
                <label id="feedback">Feedback: </label>

                <select multiple="multiple" name="feedback" size="4"  id="selectbox">
                    <option value="">Option1</option>
                    <option value="">Option1</option>
                    <option value="">Option2</option>
                    <option value="">Option3</option>
                    <option value="">Option4</option>
                    <option value="">Option5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    var ht = $("#selectbox").height();
    var ht2 = $("#feedback").height();
    ht = $("#selectbox").offset().top + (ht-ht2) / 2;
    $("#feedback").offset({ top: ht });
});
</script>
```

Comment: not worth it in anyway to write that much just so you center the text

Answer (score 0):

Strictly CSS (ID assignment on the label)

```
        <div class="element">
            <label id="feedback">Feedback: </label>

            <select multiple="multiple" name="feedback" size="4">
                <option value="">Option1</option>
                <option value="">Option1</option>
                <option value="">Option2</option>
                <option value="">Option3</option>
                <option value="">Option4</option>
                <option value="">Option5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.element select {
    height: 200px;
}

.element label#feedback {
    margin-top: 85px;
}
```